# How to link a class to Login class in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

hi I am new to Java and I have been creating Java Code for Cucumber, the scenario is that I created a Login class which covers calling the web driver, entering username and password and clicking login button, now this code is running fine, now I created a new class, this class is a new functionality inside that web page for eg AddNewUser, I don't want to code again in the AddNewUser class all code I did in the login class, how do I call the login class in AddNewUser class? I
did the following:

1. LoginSteps login = new LoginSteps(driver); - this result to an error(java: constructor LoginSteps in class StepDefinitions.LoginSteps cannot be applied to given types;
   required: no arguments
   found:    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
2. LoginSteps login = new LoginSteps(); - this results to an error (java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.manage()" because "this.driver" is null)

Below is my code to LoginSteps.java

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import pagefactory.LoginPage_PF;


public class LoginSteps {
    WebDriver driver;
    LoginPage_PF login;


    @Given("that customer wanted to login at the On Demand Portal")
    public void that_customer_wanted_to_login_at_the_On_demand_portal() {

        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath+"/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingPort(9515).build());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }
```

This is my code to AddNewUser.java

```
import StepDefinitions.LoginSteps;
import StepDefinitions.LogoutSteps;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


public class AddNewUser {
    WebDriver driver;

    LoginSteps login = new LoginSteps();

    @Given("that customer wanted to Add New User at the On Demand Portal")
    public void that_Customer_Wanted_To_Add_New_User_At_The_On_Demand_Portal() {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @And ("the user is in the On Demand Portal Dashboard")
    public void the_user_is_in_the_on_demand_portal_dashboard() {
        driver.get("URL");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

This is my code to pageFactory:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocatorFactory;

public class LoginPage_PF {

    @FindBy(name = "email")
    WebElement txt_username;

    @FindBy(name = "password")
    WebElement txt_password;

    @FindBy(css = ".MuiButton-label")
    WebElement btn_login;

    WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage_PF(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 30), this);
    }

    public void enterUsername(String username){
        txt_username.sendKeys(username);
    }

    public void enterPassword(String password){
        txt_password.sendKeys(password);
    }

    public void clickLogin(){
        btn_login.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the class `LoginSteps login = new LoginSteps();` but the `driver` is created in `LoginSteps` class and thus driver is null . I think one way is to utilize dependency injection to get the driver initialized in each scenario

You can utilize `cucumber-guice` to initialize webdriver. This will also make your tests scenarios independent as a new driver instance is created for every scenario. Here is what you can do based on how I do in my tests

To use  `cucumber-guice` dependency you will need

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and then in a global class use `@ScenarioScoped` and initialize `driver` and `LoginPage_PF`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import io.cucumber.guice.ScenarioScoped;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;  
import io.cucumber.guice.ScenarioScoped;
 
 @ScenarioScoped
    
          public class Global {
          public WebDriver driver;
           public WebDriverWait wait;
        
          public Global() {
               //implement getDriver in `loginSteps` or any other class to return driver . However , I think login steps and driver initialization should be separate
                driver = new LoginSteps().getDriver();

               //also initialize LoginPage_PF here 
                PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 30), LoginPage_PF.class);       
          }
    
    }
```

and then in you test class , which is `AddNewUser`

```
    import StepDefinitions.LoginSteps;
import StepDefinitions.LogoutSteps;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
// import Global here

    public class AddNewUser {
       
        //inject `Global` here 
          @Inject
       Global global;
    
        @Given("that customer wanted to Add New User at the On Demand Portal")
        public void that_Customer_Wanted_To_Add_New_User_At_The_On_Demand_Portal() {
            //access pageobjects . if you want to access driver for some reason for ex: opening a page , just use global.driver

            LoginPage_PF.txt_username.sendKeys("username")
            ...
            ...
         
        }
    
        @And ("the user is in the On Demand Portal Dashboard")
        public void the_user_is_in_the_on_demand_portal_dashboard() {

            // access page objects here 
        }
```

you don't need to initialize driver anywhere else other than `Global` class . More on [`cucumber-guice`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-guice/latest/io/cucumber/guice/package-summary.html)

Comment: thanks will try this one